# How do I set a static IP in ubuntu server 20.04?

Tags: networking, server, 20.04

I tried editing `/etc/network/interfaces` but the file is empty
I also tried using nmtui to edit the network configurations but it shows that there are no configurations set at all. Can anyone help?

Comment: This article found with a quick google search shows and tells you how to set a static IP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set it in `/etc/netplan/` it's quite easy. I wrote about it [here](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-configure-a-static-ip-address-in-ubuntu-server-18-04/).

Comment: You should include the steps here, and not just link to the article.

Comment: gateway4 is long deprecated and steps are not here. Down

Answer (score 2):

Static ip can be set in network settings in Ubuntu, see [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-manual.html.en).

Comment: OP is related to Ubuntu Server